# Is it possible to "install" additional development packages into the SDK

Tags: yocto, opkg

Is it possible to use the yocto SDK (created with `bitbake -c populate_sdk`) in a way, that needed (development) libraries can be installed without creating a new SDK every time?

I think about a pseudo distribution, where I can run something like `opkg install libfoo-dev` on my cross-compile host, when I want to write software which depends on libfoo, without having to build the sdk with libfoo before. I have seen bitbake creating lots of -dev-packages, but I don't know how to use them inside the SDK cross compile environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK += " libfoo "
```